# unable to print an array magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.7, cart, shipping

I am trying to print an array in magento but it does not echo anything.
In the file

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/cart/shipping.phtml
```

at around line 87 there is a piece of code something like this

```
<?php foreach ($_rates as $_rate): ?>
```

When I try to output the contents of $_rates variable using

```
<?php echo "<pre>";print_r($_rates->getData());die;?>
```

I get an error stating Call to a member function getData() on array, I understood from this that $_rates variable is an array. So when I try to use print_r($_rates) to see the content of $_rates nothing is outputted on the screen, I just get a blank screen.

My question is if $_rates is an array then why I am not able to print it on the screen.

Comment: are you sure it is not empty?

Comment: If it was empty then also array with two small brackets must have been shown on the screen. something like this : array( )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to try with below way,

```
<?php foreach ($_rates as $_rate): ?>
<?php echo "<pre>";print_r($_rate->getData());die;?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: it worked like this. But why I am not able to print $_rates on the screen if it is also an array.

Comment: just try with var_dump($_rates);

Comment: Magento objects tend to be really big. There's a lot of tight coupling of code so almost every object outputs most all of the entire loaded codebase. That's why you use `getData`. That focuses on dumping the actual data in an object rather than its whole definition.